# How can I change the colour of a specific word in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there some way to colorize a specific word with a custom color?

I'm looking at "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" but nothing seems to hint at this.

I'd like to easily discern a specific piece of code like for example a custom method from everything else, say for example in javascript you use console.log() often to help you with debugging, i'd like that specific method to have a, say, red background, but not other console methods like console.clear()

Any way to do that?

Comment: do you care whether other tokens that are textual matches of the word but are not method names get their colour changed or not?

Comment: nope, can be any text (i like the suggestion already provided by Mark!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do that easily with the extension [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight).  In your settings.json:

```json
"todohighlight.keywords": [
  {
    "text": "console.log",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "backgroundColor": "red",
    "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
  }
]
```